# count by an element in perl

Tags: perl

I have a file like:

```
fan      apple banana orange mango
cooler   apple orange banana mango
cooler   apple orange banana mango
cooler   apple orange banana mango
fan      apple banana orange mango
fan      apple banana orange mango
cooler   apple orange banana mango
fan      apple banana orange mango
```

now when I am going line by line I want to count at the moment when Fan comes and need to increase that count with every fan. like

```
count 1
fan      apple banana orange mango
cooler   apple orange banana mango
cooler   apple orange banana mango
cooler   apple orange banana mango
count 2
fan      apple banana orange mango
count 3
fan      apple banana orange mango
cooler   apple orange banana mango
count 4
fan      apple banana orange mango
```

This is what I want in output. Help is appreciated...Thank you

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n = 0;
while (<>) {
    print "count ", ++$n, "\n" if /^fan\b/;
    print;
}
```

or as a one-liner using Perl 5.10+:

```sh
perl -pE 'say "count ", ++$n if /^fan\b/'
```

Comment: You can squeeze out few strokes: `perl -pE'say"count ",++$n if/^fan\b/'` ;-)

Comment: @Hynek: Wrong site, we're not on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com :)  (Besides, if we were, `perl -pE'/^fan\b/&&say"count ",++$n'` would be one char shorter yet.)

Answer (score 0):

In a one-liner :

```
perl -lane 'BEGIN{$c=1}; $F[0] eq "fan" && do{print "count ".$c++ }; print' file
```